# Add sub subpage endpoint in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, endpoints

I already added new endpoint to my account page, "my-account/My-New-Endpoint".

I would like to add sub page endpoint to that like "my-account/My-New-Endpoint/New-Subendpoint"

I can't find any info anywhere on how to do that.

I'm specifying endpoints like so:

```
$endpoint = 'my-new-endpoint';
$endpointsub = 'my-new-endpoint/new-subendpoint';
```

That does not work it loads content from first endpoint.

If I change it to `$endpointsub = 'new-subendpoint';` it works but url becomes "my-account/New-Subendpoint"

Is there a specific way to create page/subpage endpoint to be like:"my-account/My-New-Endpoint/New-Subendpoint"?

Thank you.

EDIT:

This is add endpoint function:

```
function add_endpoints() {
        add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpoint, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
        add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpointsub, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    }
```

Comment: have your tried your last code but in defining the subendpoint first ?

Comment: WooCommerce questions are just off topic on Here… So why this question has been migrated here? It should remains on StackOvereFlow.

Comment: @mmm I just tried only changing first part and didn't change, once I did same on all parts of code it worked, example: `add_query_vars( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = self::$endpointsub;
  $vars[] = self::$endpoint;

  return $vars;
 }` Thank you. I wonder why that is? defining subpage endpoints first. In any case that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mmm and his comment defining $endpointsub before $endpoint it worked. Not sure why that is but that solved it.

So change the order of endpoints:

```
$endpointsub = 'my-new-endpoint/new-subendpoint';
$endpoint = 'my-new-endpoint';

add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpointsub, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpoint, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );

add_query_vars( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = self::$endpointsub;
        $vars[] = self::$endpoint;

        return $vars;
    }
```